# Custom footer using tikz

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, tikz-styles

I am trying to modify the footer of my `article` document using Tikz but I don't know where to start. My idea is to enclose the page number in a circle
and between lines at the footer:

`-------------------------------- ( Number ) ---------------------------`

I tried to use `scrlayer` but I keep getting the `cannot define \newpagestyle` error. Another way I think, would be to use `titlesec` but I haven't found a good example so far, for footers. I also thought on using `fancyhdr` but I saw that it is not very easy to edit.

EDIT:

Using the first answer I modified it to get this:

[image: Example]

which is what I wanted, using this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=4cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
\noindent%
\tikz[baseline]{\draw[color=back, line width=2pt] (-0.5, 0) -- (6, 0);}%
\protect\circled{\thepage}%
\tikz[baseline]{\draw[color=back, line width=2pt] (8, 0) -- (15, 0);}%
}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
\tikz[baseline]{\node[color=back, shape=circle,%
    draw, inner sep=4pt, line width=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section name}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I wanted this to match my Sections:

[image]

So, if someone has a better idea, I would appreciate it :) But the current answer is great so far

Comment: Please post a minimal document we can work with. The best approach depends heavily on not only your document class but on whether you are using any other  packages for managing headers or footers. I take it that you mean `titleps` rather than `titlesec`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I'm just using `article` as documentclass and `titlesec` to modify sections and subsections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the following code with fancyhdr package and tikz

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\dotfill \protect\circled{\thepage} \dotfill}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section name}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why dotted lines? :P Also, there is a space after the number which can be removed by removing the space before the last `\dotfill`.

Comment: yeap I did not pay attention of what type of line he wanted

Comment: Isn't TikZ a bit overkill for this...? Oh, except the OP is loading it anyway so it doesn't really matter ;).